# Inserting data into mysql database from list using Zip function

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql table with different lists, I use zip() function as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248100/inserting-list-in-specific-column-using-python) but I am getting error.

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'sheeraz' in 'field list'")
```

below is my code.

```
import Dbconnect as DB

uname =['sheeraz','ahmad','haroon','khalid']
age = [10,20,30,40]
salary = [10.55,11.55,30.55,40.55]

try:
    conn = DB.DBConnection.getConnection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for elem in zip(uname, age, salary):
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO test (name,age,salay) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)' % elem)
        conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: you can try `cur.execute('INSERT INTO test (name,age,salay) VALUES (\'%s\', %s,%s)' % elem)` to pass the first value as a string.

Comment: @MartinGergov Thank you for your support